# Custom UITableViewCell Constraints

Tags: swift

I'm creating a chat using a UITable with custom cells for the chat bubbles. Like WhatsApp, I want some bubbles to be on the left, and some to be on the right.

I'm using dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?, which calls the cell's init(style:reuseIdentifier:) method so setup my cell with:

```swift
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        cellBackground = UIView()
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = .clear
        setupConstraints()
    }

    func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellBackground.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            cellBackground.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            cellBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            cellBackground.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
        ])
    }
```

but this isn't satisfactory. The cell is always on the left, due to the leadingAnchor constraint - when the cell is on the right it needs to be a trailingAnchor constraint.

If I use a setup function for the cell, should setupConstraints be called there, or should the init setup the constraints it knows about at that time? Alternatively, should these constraints all be set up in layoutSubviews()?

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 instance variables as a references to the leading and trailing constraints inside the cell custom class

```
var leadCon,traCon:NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then inside init also but out of the activate

```
 leadCon = cellBackground.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor)
 leadCon.isActive = true
```

And

```
traCon = cellBackground.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor)
traCon.isActive = true
```

According to what you need add a func

```
func toLeft(_ value:Bool) {
   if value {
     leadCon.isActive = true
     traCon.isActive = false
   }
   else { 
     leadCon.isActive = false
     traCon.isActive = true
   }
}
```

And call it after `dequeue` line in `cellForRowAt`